# Python - Convert columns with specific base_name into rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following format of a csv file:

```
  id    a_mean_val_1 a_mean_val_2 a_var_val_1  a_var_val_2 b_mean_val_1 b_mean_val_2 b_var_val_1  b_var_val_2
```

I would like to melt the columns 1 and 2 for all a and b features into rows as follows:

```
 id     a_mean   a_var   b_mean   b_var
  1      val1     val1     val1     val1
  1      val2     val2     val2     val2
```

I am unsure how to achieve the melt function in pandas, where I could basically have an expression that matches keeps the base name: a_mean as root column and everything that has a suffix for that variable to melt them into rows.
Is there another method I could use to specify these rules?

Thank you

Comment: Don't do it on pandas.  Just read the file line by line, splitting on the commas, rearrange the columns into two rows of four and append those to a list.  Then shove your list into `pandas` after that.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
rows = []
for line in open('mycsv.csv'):
    fields = line.split(',')
    rows.append( fields[0::2] )
    rows.append( fields[1::2] )
df = pandas.DataFrame(rows, fields=['a_mean','a_var','b_mean','b_var'])
```

That doesn't provide an ID number.  Is the ID part of the CSV file?

Comment: Thank you! This is a much better approach. The answer below provides the way to convert based on the base_column name, as what I gave in the question was just a part of the dataset, and I would need that repeated for multiple more columns. Cannot keep track of which starts where. But thank you for the suggested approach!

Answer (score 0):

I went through the columns and if they were a part of a base column, then appended to a list. Finally, converted those to a dataframe.
So this code would work regardless of the order of the columns

[UPDATED WITH ID]

Since we're adding the entire columns one after the other, the ids will always start from the top, go to the end, and then repeat. So we can take "id" of the original df and multiply that by the number of rows to get the "id" for the new df.

Here's the CSV I used:
id,a_mean_val_1,a_mean_val_2,a_var_val_1,a_var_val_2,b_mean_val_1,b_mean_val_2,b_var_val_1,b_var_val_2

1,a_mean_val_1, a_mean_val_2, a_var_val_1,  a_var_val_2, b_mean_val_1 ,b_mean_val_2, b_var_val_1,  b_var_val_2

2,a_mean_val_5, a_mean_val_6, a_var_val_5,  a_var_val_6, b_mean_val_5 ,b_mean_val_6, b_var_val_5,  b_var_val_6

```
df = pd.read_csv('data_csv.csv')
# Ignore ID
columns = df.columns.tolist()[1:]
df_dict = {}
base = ['a_mean', 'a_var', 'b_mean', 'b_var']
for bas in base:
    df_dict[bas] = []
    for col in columns:
        
        # for example, "a_mean" in "a_mean_val_1" then append
        if(bas in col):
            df_dict[bas] = df_dict[bas] + df[col].tolist()
            
ids = df['id'].tolist()
df_new = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
df_new['id'] = ids*df.shape[0]

a_mean      a_var       b_mean          b_var       id
a_mean_val_1    a_var_val_1 b_mean_val_1    b_var_val_1 1
a_mean_val_5    a_var_val_5 b_mean_val_5    b_var_val_5 2
a_mean_val_2    a_var_val_2 b_mean_val_2    b_var_val_2 1
a_mean_val_6    a_var_val_6 b_mean_val_6    b_var_val_6 2
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed to use, but I also need it keep the ID as it corresponds to a user_id, is there a way to have that value of the id repeated throughout the rows corresponding to it?
Example I need to know that the first 2 rows are of user1, second 2 rows are of user with ID 2.. etc. (ID is a uuid)

Comment: Hope this works for you. If it does, please consider accepting/upvoting :)